# Unable to cancel repeating alarm Android

Tags: android, alarmmanager, repeatingalarm, receiver

I have read every question there is about Android, AlarmManager and cancelling.

I currently use an `Activity` starting a receiver through:

```
long msInterval = 1;
Intent intent = new Intent(this, Updater.class);
intent.setAction("theAction");

PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 12, intent, 0);
Updater.origin = pendingIntent;

AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis() + (msInterval), msInterval, pendingIntent);
```

This starts the receiver `Updater` one millisecond after this code was called, with request code 12 (chosen arbitrarily, using 0 produces the same incorrect behaviour). It also sets the origin of Updater to the currently scheduled PendingIntent, which is later used to cancel the alarm.

Updater looks like this:

```
public class Updater extends BroadcastReceiver {

    public static int flaggedClose = 0;
    public static PendingIntent origin;

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        // Do some work
        Log.w("running", "run");

        if (Updater.flaggedClose != 0) {
            if(flaggedClose == 1) {
                Toast.makeText(context, "Finished!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            flaggedClose++; // Only show Toast once
            Log.w("running", "close");

            origin.cancel();
            AlarmManager alarms = (AlarmManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
            alarms.cancel(origin);
        }
    }
}
```

What it does at the moment is just to log the message "run", which is done ~1000 times/s. When the Activity's `onStop()` is called, `Updater.flaggedClose` is set to `1`. I can be see this in Logcat since it starts printing the log warning "close". However, the alarm is still on, so every other logged message is "run" and every other is "close". In best case, the alarm is closed after a few seconds. Worst case I need to restart the phone. In the description of AlarmManager, it specifically states that close closes "Any alarm, of any type, whose Intent matches this one (as defined by filterEquals(Intent)), will be canceled". Why are there still alarms being triggered?

Comment: What do you mean by alarm is not cancelling?

Comment: @apurva: The alarm is still being triggered. I hoped that it would log "close" once, then `alarms.cancel(origin);` would cancel all alarms and thus no more message would be logged. Right now I can see at least a 100 more logged messages, which means that there must be 100 more alarms going off.

Comment: @Pphoenix can you increase the alarm interval to something significantly bigger (for testing purposes)? 1ms is rather short, I'm wondering, are those 100 "extra" alarms already triggered before the cancel happens. I'm not sure if the `AlarmManager` is meant for your use-case. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html read the note in *bold*

Comment: @ci_ I ran with 20ms and it works much better, though I still get a few extras. Like you said, the problem is probably that the code before `cancel` takes 1 ms or more, and thus cancel is never  executed, or more alarms scheduled in between. I will look into `Handler`.

Comment: @ci_ You were indeed correct, the alarms were created faster than they were cancelled!

Comment: if you were interested I also posted tutorial how start and stop alarm http://blog.mokrzycki.io/2015/01/working-example-of-setting-alarm-with-repeating-stuff-checking-if-alarm-was-set-with-pendingintent/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As ci_ mentioned in the comments, it is possible that "those 100 "extra" alarms already triggered before the cancel happens". For anyone else who has the same problem, here is a solution. I tested the AlarmManager and it seems to work best if you have a delay of at least 200 ms. for a lower delay use a `Handler`. Example from the question using Handler:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private boolean pressed = false;
    private boolean done = false;
    private Handler worker;
    private Runnable method;
    long msInterval = 1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        worker = new Handler();
        method = getMethod();

        Button toggle = (Button)(findViewById(R.id.toggle));
        toggle.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if(!pressed) {
                    worker.post(method);
                    pressed = true;
                } else {
                    done = true;
                }
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        done = true;
    }

    private Runnable getMethod() {
        return new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                Log.w("running", "run");
                if (done) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Finished!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    Log.w("running", "close");
                } else {
                    worker.postDelayed(method, msInterval);
                }
            }
        };
    }
}
```

On first button press the handler starts the runnable, and on each call the runnable calls itself. On second button press condition `done` is set to true, thus the runnable finishes after one (cleanup) round.